# docker run a container with an installed python script results in duplicate & improperly sequenced logs

Tags: python, docker, setup.py

I have a containerized python app. It's an app that runs tests

This is the setup.py, it essentially creates a "console script" called "tsdm" that runs my app's entry point.

```py
# setup.py
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="TSDM_Execution_Engine",
    version="0.1.dev0",
    author="Expleo TriFast",
    author_email="tsdm@expleogroup.com",
    description="",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="",
    project_urls={
        "Bug Tracker": ""
    },
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: Copyright Pending - Expleo 2021",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent"
    ],
    package_dir={"scripts": "scripts", "Test": "Test", "Generic": "Generic","Xsl": "xsl"},
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    python_requires=">=3.8.0",
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['tsdm=scripts.RunApp:main'],
    },
    include_package_data=True
)
```

This is the dockerfile

```bash
FROM ubuntu

# Install system dependencies
RUN echo "### Installing required system dependencies ###" && apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
fonts-liberation libappindicator3-1 libasound2 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libdbus-1-3 libgbm1 libnspr4 libnss3 xdg-utils \
curl unzip bzip2 wget \
xvfb python3 python3-pip

# Install Chrome current stable version
RUN CHROME_FILENAME=google-chrome.deb && echo "### Download and install chrome current stable version ###" && \
wget -O $CHROME_FILENAME "https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb" && \
dpkg -i $CHROME_FILENAME && \
apt-get install -y -f && \
rm $CHROME_FILENAME

WORKDIR /TSDM/Code/TSDM_Execution_Engine

RUN mkdir -p /TSDM/Code/TestCaseInstructionFileRepository

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

RUN pip install -e .
```

Now if I build it via

```bash
docker build . -t tsdm/test
```

and then run it with

```bash
docker run tsdm/test tsdm
```

Something strange happens, the logs appears twice, and out of order, as if it's being invoked twice simultaneously from 2 places.

but if I first shell into it via

```bash
docker run -it tsdm/test bash
```

then, once inside the container, I invoke my python script

```bash
tsdm
```

Then everything is normal.

What's going on here?

Comment: Could you please add logs for both cases?

Comment: One case you run with stdin and a tty attached, and one you don't.  Does `docker run -it tsdm/test` work?  (Make sure to set `CMD ["tsdm"]` in your Dockerfile so you don't need to repeat it when you run the image.)